# SonarQube showing 0% code coverage but JaCoCo reports are correct

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, jacoco, bamboo

We have a multi-module maven project and use the JaCoCo Maven plugin to generate the reports. For CI, we use Bamboo and SonarQube. However, in SonarQube the code coverage is always 0% although the JaCoCo reports do exist and according to build log, they also are imported by SonarQube.

Project Structure:

```
Module (root pom.xml)
  --- module
  --- module.feature
  --- module.repository
  --- module.doc
  --- module.tests
```

The root pom.xml looks like this:

```
<modules>
        <module>module</module>
        <module>module.tests</module>
        <module>module.feature</module>
        <module>module.repository</module>
        <module>module.doc</module>
</modules>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-report-aggregate</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

We also have an aggregator pom.xml where all the test plugins are defined etc.

With this config, JaCoCo reports in XML format are created in `module.tests\target\site\jacoco`. Looking at the HTML version, the report seems to be correct.
There are also empty JaCoCo reports created for the other modules, e.g. in `module.doc\target\site\jacoco` or `module.feature\target\site\jacoco`.

In the Bamboo build log we can see this for all modules:

```
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
[INFO] Importing 1 report(s). Turn your logs in debug mode in order to see the exhaustive list.
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=28ms
```

Initial thought was that maybe there is a conflict with empty reports so we also tried to put the `report-aggregate` goal only into the module.tests pom.xml which results into only one JaCoCo report but still no coverage in SonarQube.

In the Bamboo build log we would see this for the `module.tests`:

```
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
[INFO] Importing 1 report(s). Turn your logs in debug mode in order to see the exhaustive list.
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=28ms
```

For all other modules, the Bamboo build log would show this:

```
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
[WARNING] No coverage report can be found with sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths='target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml'. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
[INFO] No report imported, no coverage information will be imported by JaCoCo XML Report Importer
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=1ms
```

Both variants (`report-aggregate` in the root pom.xml OR only in the module.tests pom.xml) still result in 0% coverage in SonarQube.

As you can see from the log, we have set the sonar property `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths` accordingly. No other sonar properties have been set.

Hint: when using the `report` goal instead `report-aggregate`, the SonarQube coverage was showing but only for the test classes. So the integration between Bamboo and SonarQube seems to be there somehow.

- What am I missing here?
- Are some sonar properties maybe missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and could fix it by using "report" instead of "report-aggregate".
I also have a multi-module maven project.